# AndEngine and TimerHandlers: referencing a member variable in a scene

Tags: android, andengine

Developing a game with AndEngine GLES2

I am having an issue trying to change the scale of a rectangle that I have added to a scene from within a TimerHandlers callback. Whenever the timer ticks it makes a percentage calculation and then within the OnTimePassed ITimerCallback it tries to set the scale of the rectangle in the scene. Unless I declare the rectangle as static I keep getting a nullreferenceexception error.

I know that this is a scope issue, my question is, should I be declaring the objects I need to access from within the timercallback as static or is there an "accepted way" to get access to Activity level objects from within a timercallback?

```java
PlayerRecastTimer = new TimerHandler(0.5f, true, new ITimerCallback(){
    private float recastTime = playerSpellToCast.getRecastTime();

    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
        if(recastTime == 0) {
            mAct.GetEngine().unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            mAct.GetQueue().RemovePlayerSpell();
            pRecast.setScaleX(1);
            RunScene();
        }

        float recastScale;

        recastScale = recastTime / playerSpellToCast.getRecastTime();
        pRecast.setScaleX(recastScale); //blows up here when attempting to scale the rectangle
        recastTime -= 0.5;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `PlayerRecastTimer` is a member of a class that contains `pRecast`, then you can reference it using `ClassName.this`.

Example: If you have a class named `LoadingScreenActivity` and it has a rectangle called `pRecast`, then you can access `pRecast` in your `onTimePassed()` function by using

```
LoadingScreenActivity.this.pRecast.setScaleX(1);
```

Comment: They are both members of the same class, but even when I use the syntax you recommend I still get the NullReference.

Comment: is pRecast a class member? Usually the "p" prefix means it is a parameter variable. Which means the variable will not exist after the function completes. You may need to store a reference to the rectangle in your class, or in the TimerHandler class instead.